# append columns to pandas dataframe with duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

How can I append the columns from the `data` dataframe to the `q` dataframe, while maintaining the same order and number of rows in `q`? The challenge is that there can be duplicates in `data` and `q`.

```
In [2]: data = pd.DataFrame([[3,4,333],[5,6,111],[2,9,222],[5,6,111]], columns=['a','b','id'])

In [3]: data.index = data.id

In [4]: q = pd.DataFrame([[333],[111]], columns=['id'])

In [5]: q.index = q.id

In [6]: data
Out[6]: 
     a  b   id
id            
333  3  4  333
111  5  6  111
222  2  9  222
111  5  6  111

In [7]: q
Out[7]: 
      id
id      
333  333
111  111
```

The result should look something like:

```
   a  b   id
0  3  4  333
1  5  6  111
```

Some stuff that doesn't work:

```
pd.merge(q, data, how='left')
data.ix[q.iloc[:,0],['a','b','id']]
```

I would prefer to not do a `unique` on `data` as this would create another large object.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution without drop duplicates is create new columns in both `DataFrames` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by `id` and `g`. Last need remove column `g` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and reorder columns:

```
data['g'] = data.groupby('id').cumcount()
q['g'] = q.groupby('id').cumcount()

print (data)
     a  b   id  g
id               
333  3  4  333  0
111  5  6  111  0
222  2  9  222  0
111  5  6  111  1

print (q)
      id  g
id         
333  333  0
111  111  0

print (pd.merge(q, data, on=['id','g'], how='left')
         .drop('g', axis=1)[['a','b','id']])

   a  b   id
0  3  4  333
1  5  6  111
```

With [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) it is easy:

```
data = data.drop_duplicates('id')

print (data)
     a  b   id
id            
333  3  4  333
111  5  6  111
222  2  9  222

print (q)
      id
id      
333  333
111  111

print (pd.merge(q, data, how='left')[['a','b','id']])
   a  b   id
0  3  4  333
1  5  6  111
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join the columns of the two dataframes on a common index, `id`. Then, drop the duplicated values along with dropping off `Nans` if present as shown:

```
data[['a', 'b']].join(q['id'])                           \
                .drop_duplicates()                       \ 
                .dropna()                                \ 
                .sort_values('id', ascending=False)      \
                .reset_index(drop=True)                  \
                .astype(int)                              

   a  b   id
0  3  4  333
1  5  6  111
```